# AGALMiniAssembler is missing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, api, flash-builder, molehill

For some reason, after installing and configuring (I think) everything, the com.adobe.utils.AGALMiniAssembler is missing, everything else is ok.

I think I did everything in order to get Incubator working properly, but obviously I missed a step.

If u got any idea of why is this happening, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

EDIT.: I found the problem, happens that class doesn't come with the SDK, you need to download it manually, here is a link: http://www.bytearray.org/wp-content/projects/agalassembler/com.zip.

Comment: So you found the answer... why don't you post it as an answer so this question doesn't show up as unanswered?

Comment: Didnt know I could do that, no need to be hostile.

Comment: Wasn't trying to be hostile, just wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, happens that class doesn't come with the SDK, you need to download it manually, here is a link: http://www.bytearray.org/wp-content/projects/agalassembler/com.zip.

Answer (score 2):

warning the package in the previous message is not up to date, use this one instead :

https://github.com/PrimaryFeather/Starling-Framework/blob/master/starling/src/com/adobe/utils/AGALMiniAssembler.as